# REST API naming convention issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have a controller that handles CRUD operations on quizzes, called QuizController.

Then, a user can go take the current quiz (there's only one available at a time).

It's tempting to name that controller QuizController as well, and I could if it were namespaced differently. But that isn't innately descriptive enough to me.

It could be called QuizResultsController. But that's not great either.

How would you name such a controller that displays the current quiz to a user and let's them submit their answers?

Answer (score 1):

The controller that handles CRUD operations for your quizzes should, by convention, be called `QuizzesController`, freeing up `QuizController` for use in the context you've described.

That said, I'd go with `QuizzesController` and `CurrentQuizController` to make the distinction greater.

Comment: You're right, it is already QuizzesController, my bad. I think you're also on the right track in your suggested controller names. Only concern is, if the plans were to change to where more than one quiz could be taken at any given time, a lot of changes might be required. I may go with it though... Thanks!

Comment: I know, this is a little different than the original question, but I'm curious what you'd call the controller if it were for a user taking one of any number of quizzes?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `#current` action on `QuizzesController` which shows the current quiz if you didn't want to create an entire single-purpose controller.

Comment: Then I'd have to add yet another method to handle the form submission with something vague like #current_create. I'm striving for single-responsibility.

Comment: Why couldn't you use the conventional methods on `QuizzesController` to handle quiz creation and updating? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I thought you were just needing to display the current quiz to the user so he/she can take it. I imagine `QuizzesController#current` renders a view that has a form that the user submits to `QuizzesController#update` after taking it. I don't see that you'd have to special-case anything unless you wanted to render/redirect to somewhere based on coming from either a current quiz or another quiz.

Comment: Depends. If I had a separate admin section, I'd usually have something like an `Admin::QuizzesController`. If there's no admin section, then there's a definite case for a `QuizzesController` and a `CurrentQuizController` (or whatever it's called).

Comment: "whatever it's called" is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: agreed with @JoshuaRieken, I also think its good to have a method (Ex: current) in 'QuizzesController', without over complicating the controllers , and as he proposed you could use the same #update to go with the user input for #current (unless otherwise you have a special requirement) :)